# Calculating time complexity of Peak finding Algorithm (2D)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I want to calculate the time complexity of 2D peak finding algorithm. But i don't know how can i calculate it. Please any one explain it to me line by line and solve it.
How they get this answer  **Ɵ(n log m)**. from the equation **T(n,m)= T(n,m/2) + Ɵ(n).** Thanks

Following 2D algorithm and pdf slides from a lecture. link is http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.006/fall10/lectures/lec02.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Ɵ(n)` doesn't depend on `m`, so we actually are just summing these `Ɵ(n)' "several" times.

This "several" is how many times we can divide `m` by `2` before getting `1` - that's `log2(m)`.

So we get `Ɵ(n)*log2(m) = Ɵ(n*log2(m))`.